# Haskell List comprehension: show even and double odd elements

Tags: list, haskell, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I've been working on an assignment and I just can't get it to work.

I should write a function that takes a list of numbers and gives back a list that shows even numbers but doubles all odd numbers. (Basically the same list but with doubled odds).

```
doubleOdd :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleOdd [] = []
doubleOdd a = [x*2 | x <- a, odd x]
```

My problems are:

1. I'm only allowed to use +, -, *, /, ==, /=, sum, mod, elem, maximum, odd, even
2. I don't know how I get different conditions for the same value to work (like if x is even = x and in the same List Comprehension have: if x is odd = x*2)

So far I only got to print the even or the odd numbers, but never both.....

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: you don't have to filter (`,odd x`) at all (if I get your question right) instead think about how you could change the mapping-part (`x*2`) to do what you want (*hint:* `if ... then ... else ...` is an expression you could use there)

Comment: Additional hint: `odd x == not (even x)` for all numbers - and in the `else` part you see what happens if the condition of your `if` is `not true` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are looking for a *math-trick* version:

```hs
> take 10 $ [ x + (x `mod` 2) * x | x <- [1..] ]
[2,2,6,4,10,6,14,8,18,10]
```

(you can do lot's of cheating like this with `mod`)

Comment: ah, yes indeed, ``(`mod` 2)`` *is* `if even...`

Comment: Wow this is impressive.  Consider my mind blown 0_0

Answer (score 2):

In the recursive case treat both possible cases, the case of odds and the case of evens, with the two mutually exclusive tests:

```
doubleOdd a = [ .... | x <- a, y <- ([x*2 | .... x] ++ [x | .... x]) ]
```

Since the two tests are mutually exclusive, there will be only one result.

You either must use `++`, or the `if...then...else`. I don't see a way to do this without one or the other.

Or maybe it can be done with some arithmetic trick but then it'd be a math question, not a Haskell question.

Comment: With `if...then...else` it would be no problem, this is the main problem for me. Thank you very much for the `y  <-  ([x*2 | ... x]` part. I didn't know that you can do something like that in Haskell.

Comment: the parentheses are optional. I've put them in specifically so you'd see it's not `y  <-  ([x*2 | ... x]` but `y  <-  (   [x*2 | ... x] ++ [x | .... x]   )`. or maybe that's what you meant. :) cheers and you're welcome. the `(   [x*2 | ... x] ++ [x | .... x]   )` is just a way to avoid `if`, when the two tests are mutually exclusive -- at the cost of potentially running a superfluous test which wouldn't be needed, with `if`.